# How to configure backend URL in Protractor (frontend project)

Tags: angular, gulp, protractor

I have two separate projects. One frontend (Angular V6) and another backend (Springboot v2).

I'm trying to implement e2e tests with Protractor, however I can't configure the backend URL correctly in the frontend project.

My protractor.conf.js:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 900000000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

The backend project is running at this address: http://localhost:8080/

The frotend project is running at this address: http://localhost:4200/

When opening the test page, the frontend project tries to access a service at the following url: http://localhost:4200/car/

and it should be at this URL: http://localhost:8080/car

And so the test breaks because there is no such URL: http://localhost:4200/car.

So the question is:
Is there any way I can configure the backend URL in the frontend project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can setup angular proxy to forward some endpoints to your backend.
create proxy.conf.js

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/car",
            "/anything"
        ],
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        secure: false
    }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

and add it to your angular.cli serve configuration

```
....
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
    },
```